# This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named ca_public_key_pem

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to access the `ca_public_key_pem` property of my `tls_self_signed_cert` object, but I'm being told that the property does not exist.

Yet in the source code, and examples for this module, it appears to be present.

[GitHub Source Code](https://github.com/hashicorp-modules/tls-self-signed-cert/blob/master/outputs.tf)

```
output "ca_public_key_pem" {
  value = "${chomp(element(concat(tls_private_key.ca.*.public_key_pem, list("")), 0))}" # TODO: Workaround for issue #11210
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get the public key for the CA certificate in PEM format from a tls_self_signed_cert resource?

I'm currently using the module as follows:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "RootKey" {
    algorithm = "RSA"
    rsa_bits  = 2048
}

resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "SelfSigned" {
    key_algorithm   = "${tls_private_key.RootKey.algorithm}"
    private_key_pem = "${tls_private_key.RootKey.private_key_pem}"

    subject {
        common_name  = "Domain.com"
        organization = "Org Name"
    }

    is_ca_certificate     = true
    validity_period_hours = 26280
    early_renewal_hours   = 8760
    allowed_uses          = ["cert_signing"]
}
```

and then in my `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` configuration, I have the following:

```
...
    vpn_client_configuration {
        address_space        = ["10.9.0.0/24"]
        vpn_client_protocols = ["IkeV2"]

        root_certificate {
            name             = "My-Root-CA"
            public_cert_data = "${tls_self_signed_cert.SelfSigned.ca_public_key_pem}"
        }
    }
```

I've tried using `cert_pem` but it's not valid for this property.

Comment: How are you using this module?

Comment: have updated the question with my usage. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also include the `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` definition too please?

Comment: I don't understand how that will aid in the solving of the problem?  Can you please explain.  The virtual gateway is already setup and running without problem.  It's just adding the root_certificate public_cert_data property that is causing it to fail.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're using the output from the `tls_self_signed_cert` resource wrong from your error but it's impossible to tell without seeing it. The general guidance is that your question should include a [mcve] that people can run and reproduce your error exactly. Without that it's impossible to determine what's wrong. Alternatively if you can reproduce the same error from an even more minimal configuration without a `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` resource then that would be even better.

Comment: I've also tried creating a public_key_pem using the tls_public_key data source and providing it with the private key private_key_pem property, but it didn't like the format of that data either.

Comment: The output attribute is just [`cert_pem`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tls/r/self_signed_cert.html#cert_pem).

Comment: I've tried that one, but it's not valid as input to the public_cert_data attribute.  So my question remains, how does one get the public cert data in pem format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` `public_cert_data`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_network_gateway.html#public_cert_data) unusually requires the cert to be in PEM format but without the traditional `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` markers:

> The root_certificate block supports:
>
> - `name` - (Required) A user-defined name of the root certificate.
> - `public_cert_data` - (Required) The public certificate of the root
>     certificate authority. The certificate must be provided in Base-64
>     encoded X.509 format (PEM). In particular, this argument must not
>     include the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`
>     markers.

The [`tls_self_signed_cert`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tls/r/self_signed_cert.html) resource has the [`cert_pem`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tls/r/self_signed_cert.html#cert_pem) attribute that it outputs but this does have the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` markers.

So if you want to chain these through then you'll need to remove these markers. The easiest way to do this is use the [`replace`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/replace.html) function.

A minimal example of this output would look like this:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm   = "ECDSA"
  ecdsa_curve = "P384"
}

resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "example" {
  key_algorithm   = "ECDSA"
  private_key_pem = "${tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem}"

  subject {
    common_name  = "example.com"
    organization = "ACME Examples, Inc"
  }

  validity_period_hours = 12

  allowed_uses = [
    "key_encipherment",
    "digital_signature",
    "server_auth",
  ]
}

output "cert" {
  value = "${tls_self_signed_cert.example.cert_pem}"
}

output "trimmed_cert" {
  value = "${replace(replace(tls_self_signed_cert.example.cert_pem, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", ""), "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")}"
}
```

Applying this out will output the following:

```
Outputs:

cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

trimmed_cert = 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```

This trimmed output, made from the two `replace` functions should be usable for the `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` `public_cert_data` parameter.